# Loading Byte image on SSRS from database

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008

How to load Byte data into the image box of SSRS
The data is saved in the image field of the database.

Could you give me expression for it?

Thanks / Furqan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the image object in the report --> Image Properties, you will see this dialog:

In "Use this field: " select your dataset value that contains the image info

In "Use this MIME type:" select the type of image file it is (jpg,png,bmp etc)

[image]

Comment: Just dragged the image field from my data source over the picture box and it worked..................